# How to redirect to a new domain using API Gateway with URL params?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

I've been using API Gateway to create free HTTPS redirects from one domain to another. But today, I need to include all the URL parameters in the redirect. For example:

`example.com/articles/fun-article?source=google&something=else`

to

`www.example.com/articles/fun-article?source=google&something=else`

I was going over the CloudFormation API Gateway docs and couldn't find anything that could allow me to do so. And I was wondering if I'm missing something. So, for example here is the part of the CFN that does the redirect:

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
    "type": "mock",
    "responses": {
        "301": {
            "statusCode": "301",
            "responseParameters": {
                "method.response.header.Location": "'https://tmmwith.us/'"
            }
        }
    },
    "requestTemplates": {
        "application/json": "{\"statusCode\": 301}"
    },
    "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match"
}
```

In the `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` resource, any ideas if there is a way to mention in the `method.response.header.Location` to include all the parameters of the URL?